# Catching all exception

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I have a project that might throw exception on any function and object, is there a way to catch any and all exception throughout the framework/program so that I can log them so that I can see them later? I would want the call stack and the exception message. I don't necessarily know where the exception is going to throw, but I want to log any exception that occurs anywhere throughout the lifetime of the program. Is there anyway to do this? I don't want to do try and catch on any possible exception throwing function. The program will break because of unhandled exception, but I want to log it first.

Comment: Is this a web, win form or other type of project?

Comment: Windows desktop app, specifically WCF.

Comment: Do you mean it's a WCF service, self-hosted in a Windows Forms application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch exceptions at the app domain level -[App Domain Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
```

If you read the link it mentions that some other events may cause the app domain not to fire - such as ThreadException - so more than one handler may be required.

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler (ThreadExceptionHandler);
```

and also note the following: (in relation to winforms -  [SetUnhandledExceptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode.aspx))

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

Comment: `Application` is just for winforms. you might want to mention that.

Answer (score 3):

yes, there is a way to do that.
Write following lines in the main:

```
// Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(MainForm_UIThreadException);

// Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through
// our handler.
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

// Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
    new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

and than handle the exceptions

```
private static void MainForm_UIThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs t)
{
    //do something
}

private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A major point for catching exceptions is to handle them properly based on the type of exception thrown. By having one big exception handler, you're unable to handle individual exceptions and instead are likely to just be swallowing them. But that's not to say it can't be done or shouldn't be done in all cases.

If your project requires one big handler, then you could simply handle the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event. Even if you're catching exceptions elsewhere, handling this method is a good idea to ensure your program doesn't just throw an unfriendly error when you've missed an exception. This assumes you're creating a `WinForm`.

Since you're also using `WCF`, you can take a look at the [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) interface to help handle fault messages.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to catch any and all exception throughout the framework/program so that I can log them so that I can see them later?

The only way to catch all unhandled exceptions for ***all*** application types is to use the already mentioned `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`. However, you can not prevent your application from terminating using that event (well, you can, but I won't tell how since it's kind of hackish).

There are however ways to catch unhandled exceptions in most frameworks which allow you to just lok the exception and move on. Since you mentioned WCF you might want to read about [IErrorHandler](http://www.bing.com/search?q=ierrorhandler&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC)

> I don't want to do try and catch on any possible exception throwing function.

That's how I do it. [Do NOT catch that exception](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125118/Do-NOT-catch-that-exception). ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could always use [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppDomain_UnhandledException);
}

private static void AppDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) {
    Logger.Log((Exception)args.ExceptionObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to catch any and all exception throughout the
>   framework/program so that I can log them so that I can see them later?

**Yes**, there are handlers for desktop applications or web applications to handle unhandled exceptions.  In desktop apps the event is called UnhandledException.  In web applications it is the Application_Error on you application entry point(usually Global.asax.cs).

> I don't want to do try and catch on any possible exception throwing
>   function. The program will break because of unhandled exception, but I
>   want to log it first.

You can always simply rethrow if you don't want to catch the exception.  It will continue to bubble up to crash the program.

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //logging here
    throw;//rethrow
}
```

> I would want the call stack and the exception message.

The `Exception` class contains these.  In the case of the event handlers, there are various ways to access depending on what type of application it is.